# How to remove a directory without removing its content?

Tags: command-line, directory, rm

Let's say that I have a directory `/home/smit/test`. Inside it I have many subdirectories and files. I want to remove only the Directory `/home/smit/test`  and not its inner content, So that files and subdirectories of `/home/smit/test` will automatically be included in `/home/smit/`?

Also, in a real case I have `/usr/share/backgrounds/all/` directory which has many subdirectories. and theses sub directories have lots of images. I want to remove all subdirectories So that their contents will be included in `/usr/share/backgrounds/all/`. I can do this with GUI but I want to do it with cool way by terminal. How can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In these situations there is a risk of files with the same name being overwritten. As mentioned by @Arronical, you can avoid this using the `-b` flag to `mv` which causes any identically named files to be differentiated by appending `~` to their names. However, if there are three or more files with the same name, only the first and last will be saved, so check the contents before moving to protect your files.

The first, simple case is easy; we can use a shell glob. However, this won't move hidden files, so if you have any filenames beginning with `.`, start by turning on `dotglob`

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Then you can run:

```
mv -b /home/smit/test/* /home/smit
rmdir /home/smit/test
```

Turn off `dotglob` if you like (it will return to default anyway when you open a new shell):

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

For the second (real) case, we will use `find`, which moves hidden files by default:

Make sure you are in the right location first.

```
cd /usr/share/background/all
find -type f -exec echo mv -vb -- {} . \;
```

If that looks good, run it without `echo` to actually move files

```
find -type f -exec mv -vb -- {} . \;
```

Then find the directories

```
find -type d
```

If you see what you want to remove:

```
find -type d -delete
```

This is safe since it will refuse to remove directories that still have contents.

Comment: You can also use the `-b` or `--backup` options of `mv` to cope with duplicate filenames, and make backups of the original versions.

Comment: Thanks.Now I am More cool.But I still need to take a look at man page of find to become more cooler   : )

Comment: Other subdirectories are gone but,linuxmint directory is not deleting.It says this:-`find: cannot delete ‘./linuxmint’: Directory not empty` But other files were also not empty.I didn't find any info in man page.It holds file `default_background.jpg` which I can't open even from GUI.

Comment: @SMITPATIL the directories should all have been emptied by the move operation. I assume you actually needed to run `find -type f -exec sudo mv -vb -- {} . \;` (because `mv` actions are write operations), but if not, were there any permission errors? Would you like to start a chat room to figure out what is happening?

Comment: yes but how can I open chat room?

Comment: @SMITPATIL You can go to chat and create on, but [I made one already :)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62906/directory-not-empty)

Comment: Just to confirm: Does is this handling of duplicates also safe if you have multiple files with the same name? For instance in case 2: `a/i.jpg` `a/b/i.jpg` `a/c/i.jpg`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin good question - no it only rescues the last duplicate. Edited the post!

Comment: In that case that would be `find SOURCE -type f -exec mv -bt TARGET -- {} + && rm -rf SOURCE`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster that's smart :D