# How do I use the exec command inside a for loop after a find command?

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I've been trying to get this working for a while now. I want to search for a list of files and then copy them all to a certain path.

If I run the command separately, then it works like so:

```
find <path> -name 'file1' -exec cp '{}' <path2> \;
```

But I've been unable to run it inside a for loop.

```
#this works
for f in file1 file2 file3...; do find <path> -name "$f" \; done;
#none of these work (this code tries to find and copy the files named file and list from the path)
for f in file1 file2 file3...; do find <path> -name "$f" -exec cp '{}' <path2> \; done;
for f in file1 file2 file3...; do find <path> -name "$f" -exec cp {} <path2> \; done;
```

I've tried a few other stuff that weren't likely to work. The first line in the code quote just gets stuck and the others don't copy anything even though they don't get stuck.

I haven't been able to run anything with exec inside a for loop after a search and at this point I'm not sure what to do.

I have solved the immediate problem by searching the files and logging the results to another file and then running a copy inside a for loop separately but I'd still like to know how to do this.

Comment: are you really using single quotes for your variable? The shell has to do parameter expansion for the `for` loop to work... and I don't understand why you would need to do this! If you pass the file list, why do you need to `find` the files too? why not, `for f in file list; do cp "$f" <path2>; done`?

Comment: @Zanna I'm not really proficient in bash. Just trying different combinations to see what works and you're partially right. Although I have to search for the files because they're not in the same place on all the PCs. So, if I give the absolute paths, the code works but I want to search for the files.

Comment: @Zanna There. I've edited it just for you.

Comment: Can you try like this `for f in file1 file2 file3; do find /path -name "$f" -exec cp -vt /path/to/test/dir -- {} +; done`?

Comment: @Zanna yup that works. Make that into an answer, and explain if you can, and I'll pick it as soon as possible. Thank you :)

Comment: `#this works for f in file1 file2 file3...; do find <path> -name "$f" \; done;` - No it doesn't! (unterminated for-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the other answers are correct I want to offer a different approach that doesn't require multiple invocations of `find` to scan the same directory structure repeatedly. The basic idea is to use `find` to

1. generate a list of files that match the common criteria,
2. apply a custom *filter* to that list, and
3. perform some action, e. g. `cp`, on the entries of the filtered list.

#### Implementation 1

(requires Bash to read null-byte-delimited records)

```
find /some/path -type f -print0 |
while read -rd '' f; do
  case "${f##*/}" in
    file1|file2|file3)
      printf '%s\0' "$f";;
  esac
done |
xargs -r0 -- cp -vt /some/other/path --
```

Each pipe corresponds to the beginning of the next step of the three steps described above.

The `case` statement has the advantage of allowing [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) matches. Alternatively you could use Bash's [conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html):

```
if [[ "${f##*/}" == file1 || "${f##*/}" == file2 || "${f##*/}" == file3 ]]; then
  printf '%s\0' "$f"
fi
```

### Implementation 2

If the list of file names to match is a bit longer and cannot be replaced with a small set of [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) patterns, or if the list of file names to match is not known at the time of writing, you can resort to an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) that holds the list of file names of interest:

```
FILE_NAMES=( "file1" "file2" "file3" ... )

find /some/path -type f -print0 |
while read -rd '' f; do
  for needle in "${FILE_NAMES[@]}"; do
    if [ "${f##*/}" = "$needle" ]; then
      printf '%s\0' "$f"
    fi
  done
done |
xargs -r0 -- cp -vt /some/other/path --
```

### Implementation 3

As a variation we can use an [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) which hopefully has faster look-up times than plain "list" arrays:

```
declare -A FILE_NAMES=( ["file1"]= ["file2"]= ["file3"]= ... )  # Note the superscripts with []=

find /some/path -type f -print0 |
while read -rd '' f; do
  if [ -v FILE_NAMES["${f##*/}"] ]; then
    printf '%s\0' "$f"
  fi
done |
xargs -r0 -- cp -vt /some/other/path --
```

Answer (score 7):

Two issues:

1. `for f in some_file` does not iterate over the content of `some_file`, just iterate over or take the literal string `some_file`. To get over this forget about `for` looping for iterating over file content, use a properly implemented `while` construct.
2. Variables won't be expanded when put inside single quotes, `'$f'` in this case. To get your original idea working, use double quotes.

Putting these together, assuming the filenames are newline separated inside `file_list` file:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r f; do 
    find /path1 -name "$f" -exec cp '{}' /path2 \;
done <file_list
```

Or if you know the files would be in the `/path1` directory, not under any subdirectory of it, you can just use an array to get the filenames, and use (GNU) `cp` directly, again assuming newline separated filenames inside `file_list`:

```
( 
 IFS=$'\n'
 files=( $(<file_list) )
 cp -t /path2 "${files[@]}"
)
```

In case of huge number of files, you would be better off iterating over and `cp` individually rather than dumping into an array:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do cp -- "$f" /path2; done <file_list
```

---

If you have file list like e.g. `file1 file2 file3 ...` directly in the `for` construct, then just using double quotes would do:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do 
    find /path1 -name "$f" -exec cp '{}' /path2 \;
done
```

Now, you can use `cp` directly here too if all files would not be in any subdirectory:

```
cp -t /path2 file1 file2 file3
```

Or you can give static absolute or relative paths in case you want to use `cp` only to deal with any files under any subdirectory.

Comment: I need to find the files in the subfolders. I've tried your suggestions and they don't work (they get stuck and don't move on). I have the file list in the for construct like you have suggested in your last example of the for loop. Like so: `for f in file1 file2 file3; do find /path1 -name "$f" -exec cp '{}' /path2 \; done` P.S. the directory is not big so searching for one file is done instantlt and I'm trying to do this with just one file as well (for f in file1; etc.) and that's not working either.

Comment: @JohnHamilton Please define *don't work*, and also show the exact command you have run.

Comment: It doesn't work as in the previous cases. It does nothing just hangs there with a new line forever.

Comment: @JohnHamilton You definitely didn't use what I've used. Check the commands in my answer again...

Answer (score 5):

You clarified that your file list is not a text file, but a series of filenames you want to find with `find`. You mentioned that this works for you:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3 ... ; do find <path> -name "$f" \; done;
```

presumably you mean you get the expected list of files from that command.

You then say this does not work:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3 ... ; do find <path> -name "$f" -exec cp '{}' <path2> \; done
```

presumably you mean the files listed before aren't copied to `<path2>`. I'm not sure what error you're getting, but as it's written, I'd expect that command to hang like this:

```
$for f in file1 file2 file3 ... ; do find <path> -name "$f" -exec cp '{}' <path2> \; done
>
```

waiting for the missing `;`. Assuming you corrected that problem, I can't think of any other obvious reason why your command would definitely fail. You *should* be able to manage with

```
for f in file1 file2 file3 ... ; do find <path> -name "$f" -exec cp '{}' <path2> \; ; done
```

However I suggest using the `-t` flag to specify the directory. I have to thank [David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster) for [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940256/how-to-remove-a-directory-without-removing-its-content/940260#comment1492504_940260) which I think shows the best form for a `cp` or `mv` invocation using `find`. It will refuse to overwrite duplicate files too.

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do find /path/to/search -name "$f" -exec cp -vt /path/to/destination -- {} + ; done
```

#### Notes

- `-v` be verbose - tell us what is being done
- `-t` use the specified directory as destination
- `--` don't accept any further options
- `+` if there are multiple matches (in your case this is unlikely since `for` will run once for each item in the file list, but there may be multiple matching files for each name), then construct an argument list for `cp` instead of running `cp` multiple times
- `;` separates commands in the shell. The form of a `for` loop is

  ```
  for var in things; do command "$var"; done
  ```

  If it doesn't see the `;` before `done`, bash will wait for `;` or an interrupt signal.

Comment: Very detailed and thorough answer, thank you.  I've tried that other command with the extra semicolon, it ran the command but without copying anything to the directory. I now think that it was trying to copy to the name of the file instead of the directory specified.

Comment: After a few more trials, this one started working and I'm not sure why it didn't work before: `for f in file1 file2 file3 ... ; do find <path> -name "$f" -exec cp '{}' <path2> \; ; done`